# Connect Remotely to SQL Server Express instance hosted on Google Compute Engine

Tags: sql-server-express, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to access SQL Server Express installed on Windows Server 2012 on Google Compute Engine VM. I have assigned STATIC IP to the instance and also added an exception to the firewall in Windows for port 1433 as well as in via console area of Compute Engine and allowed my IP in authentication.

I tried connecting the instance remotely via STATIC IP and Instance Name (`IP\instancename`) using SQL Server authentication, I have also configured SQL Server to accept remote connections as well as enabled TCP/IP from Configuration Area.

I'm still unable to connect to the Instance remotely can any one suggest me how to do.

Comment: You failed to mention what the issue is

Comment: I'm Unable to Connect to the Instance Remotely and need solution

Comment: try " telnet IP_ADDRESS 1433 " if you can not connect so there is a problem with firewalls in the server side or the client side or the SQL service is not running.

Comment: @Kamran I tried IP Address and Port in Windows Telnet Console cursor was blinking and after sometime got a prompt (Press any key to Continue...) on doing so screen shows (Connection Lost ), Just to make sure i made a change in port instead of 1433 i entered 1434 which is not in firewall anywhere and i get an error Could not open connection to PORT.

Comment: sounds like your firewall settings on the server side is good and lets in traffic on port 1433. Can you paste a screenshot of the error you receive when trying to connect with the SQL client.

Comment: facing the same issue. Even via Telnet cant able to connect . It displaying  `Trying xxx.196.20.yyy...`   
`telnet: connect to address xxx.196.20.yyy: Operation timed out`  
`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`