# SQL remote connection not working on google compute engine

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute engine with a static IP address running widows server 2012 with SQL server 2012 express. 
I have enabled SQL remote connections by following the instructions [here](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) and have setup windows firewall and google firewall to allow connections on port 1433.  I also verified that SQL engine is running.
I have tested the port connection with telnet and it's allowing the connection.
The problem is that i still am not able to connect to the server.
error:

> a network related or instance specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection .... error 26 error locating server
>   specified

Here's the connection string im using

> "Data Source=IP Address\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbname;User Id=xyz;Password=123;"

A user posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793240/connect-remotely-to-sql-server-express-instance-hosted-on-google-compute-engine) but i am able to telnet my server. 
I have used the same steps before with a AWS server and everything worked perfect. Is there other steps that have to be done with a google compute server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in the connection string. 
I ended up switching to Amazon AWS servers and the following connection string works.

```
"Data Source=ec2-00-000-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com,PORT#;Database=test;User Id=xyz;Password=1234;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to connect from a remote machine outside of GCP, then have you looked inside your SQL Server Firewall Rules, under the Advanced tab,the Edge Traversal setting?
[Edge Traversal Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyX8V.png)